# Question to semigroup of translations and first hitting time

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, markov-process, stopping-times, semigroup-of-operators

Let $(B_t, \mathcal{F}_t, P_x)$ be the Markov process associated with standard Brownian motion and let $\theta_t : \Omega \to \Omega$ (,$t \geq 0$) be  the associated semigroup of translations with

a)$\theta_0 = Id_{\Omega}$,
b)$\theta_{s+t} = \theta_s \circ \theta_t$, $\forall s,t \geq 0$,
c) $X_s \circ \theta_t = X_{s+t}$, $\forall s,t \geq 0$

Furthermore, we defined $\tau_a := \inf\{t\geq 0: B_t=a\}$ and
$\tau_a (t) := \min\{s\geq t: B_s=a\}$, if there exists an $s$ with $B_s = a$ (else: $\tau_a (t) = \infty$) .
Can you tell me why the following equalities hold:

$\{ \tau_{-a} < \infty \} \cap \theta_{\tau_{-a}}^{-1} \{ \tau_a < \infty \} = \{ \omega \in \Omega_{\tau_{-a}} : \tau_a (\theta_{\tau_{-a} (\omega)} (\omega)) < \infty \} = \{ \tau_{-a} < \infty \} \cap \{ \tau_a (\tau_{-a}) < \infty \}$

Thank you very much for any hint!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming $\tau-a$s are typos and should be replaced with $\tau_{-a}$. Also, what is $\Omega_{\tau-a}$ (or $\Omega_{\tau_{-a}}$)?

$\Omega = C([0,\infty),\mathbb{R}^d)$ and $(\theta_t(\omega))_s = \omega_{s+t}$ for $\omega \in \Omega$.

Note that the path $\theta_{\tau_{-a}(\omega)}(\omega)$ starts from $-a$ for each $\omega \in \Omega$. Then $$\{\omega \in \Omega \mid \tau_{-a}(\omega)<\infty\}\cap\{\omega \in \Omega \mid \tau_a (\theta_{\tau_{-a}(\omega)}(\omega)) < \infty\} = \text{All paths which hit $-a$ in finite time and after that hit $a$ agian in finite time }.$$

The other terms in the equality are just restatements of the middle term, e.g.
$$\theta_{\tau_{-a}(\cdot)}^{-1}\{\tau_{a} < \infty\} = \{\omega \in \Omega \mid \theta_{\tau_{-a}(\omega)}(\omega) \in \{\tau_{a} < \infty\} \} = \{\omega \in \Omega \mid \tau_a (\theta_{\tau_{-a}(\omega)}(\omega)) < \infty\}$$

Comment: Thank you very much Sayantan. That's right, I will correct my typos. I am still wondering why the shift operator $\theta_{\tau_{-a} (\omega)} (\omega)$ is a shift to $-a$, because I am thinking that the shift operator is defined as a shift to the left of the timeline under the assumption that we plug in positive values.

Comment: By definition of $\tau_{-a}$ and $\theta$, $$(\theta_{\tau_{-a}(\omega)}(\omega))_0 = \omega_{\tau_{-a}(\omega)} = -a.$$